# Understanding How a Circle is Formed in Processing

Tags: java, audio, processing, geometry

```
import ddf.minim.*;

Minim minim;
AudioPlayer player;
PImage img;

void setup() {
  size(728, 546);

  minim = new Minim(this);

  player = minim.loadFile("Bassnectar_-_Magical_World_feat.wav");
  player.play();
  img= loadImage("cat-in-shades-.jpg");
}

void draw() {


  image(img, 0, 0);
  tint(0, 100, 150);
  stroke(255);

  strokeWeight(4);
  float a = 0;

  float angle = (2*PI) / 200;


  for(int i=0; i < player.bufferSize() - 1; i++) {

   //player.mix.get(i) is a value between [-1,1]

    float x = 250 + cos(a) * (20 * player.mix.get(i) + 100);
    float x2 = 540 + cos(a) * (20 * player.mix.get(i) + 100);    

    float y = 230 + sin(a) * (20 * player.mix.get(i) + 100);
    float y2 = 240 + sin(a) * (20 * player.mix.get(i) + 100);


    float xFinal = 250 + cos(a+angle) * (20 * player.mix.get(i+1) + 100);
    float x2Final = 540 + cos(a+angle) * (20 * player.mix.get(i+1) + 100);


    float yFinal = 230 + sin(a+angle) * (20 * player.mix.get(i+1) + 100);    
    float y2Final = 240 + sin(a+angle) * (20 * player.mix.get(i+1) + 100);    


    line(x,y,xFinal,yFinal);
    line(x2,y2,x2Final,y2Final);

    a += angle;

  }

}

void stop() {
  player.close();
  minim.stop();

  super.stop();
}
```

The following code above is for creating an audio visualizer in Processing with the Minim library. For some reason I'm struggling to see how a circle is formed within the the code's for loop. 
In general I'm also trying to break down the code and get a deeper understanding for what is going on. I am confused about the following:
    'float x = 250 + cos(a) * (20 * player.mix.get(i) + 100);'
Is the 20 times and plus 100 used to scale up the sample? If so then why does the circle visualizer not display when I get rid of the 20 times and just have plus 20000? Is the 250 used for placement of the start point of the line on the x-axis within the background image? 
Lastly, why is the variable 'angle' needed? When I take it out I notice the visualizer is not as smooth as there looks to be a division between the quadrants.
I have been playing around with this code, and can't find too many examples with detailed explanations so any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing you need to do is understand basic trigonometry better. There are a ton of resources out there: try googling "sin cos tutorial" or "sin and cos for game development" or "sohcahtoa" for a bunch of results.

But basically, if you have a start point, a rotation, and a distance, you can figure out where the end point is using `sin` and `cos`. The basic formula for calculating an end point is this:

```
endX = startX + cos(rotation)*distance;
endY = startY + sin(rotation)*distance;
```

Your code is using this formula to find points around a circle so that it can draw lines between them to draw the circle. Each line section of the circle is 2 of the end points.

The `angle` variable is used to specify how far apart those points are. The smaller you make it, the more "circle-y" it will look. The larger you make it, the more you'll be able to see the straight lines that make up the circle.

It might be easier to work with a simpler example:

```
void setup(){
  size(500, 500);
}

void draw(){
  background(0);

  //draw white
  stroke(255);

  //the start point- try changing this to mouseX and mouseY
  float centerX = width/2;
  float centerY = height/2;

  //the distance from the start point
  float radius = 100;

  //how far apart the points are
  float angleIncrement = 30;

  //loop to go around the circle. Try changing it to 180 to see what happens.
  for(float angleInDegrees = 0; angleInDegrees <= 360; angleInDegrees+=angleIncrement){

    //the first "end point" is the start point of the line
    float startX = centerX + cos(radians(angleInDegrees))*radius;
    float startY = centerY + sin(radians(angleInDegrees))*radius;

    //the second "end point" is the end point of the line
    //notice that we're adding the angleIncrement to the angle to get the next point
    float endX = centerX + cos(radians(angleInDegrees+angleIncrement))*radius;
    float endY = centerY + sin(radians(angleInDegrees+angleIncrement))*radius;

    //draw the line
    line(startX, startY, endX, endY);

  }
}
```